# Display thai characters on Page PHP / Thai chars ok in DB at server

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I am trying to show Thai Characters in my app PHP / MySQL, data is being inserted from a backend process to the database and Thai chars are in the Database, but are not show in the front end. PHP.

I have tried with UTF-8 encoding in the page, and Windows-874

What is the right combination for this to be shown correct in the Browser?
see image

[image]
 [enter link to image bigger size](http://screencast.com/t/Tdbz7dIMIv)
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site where you enter the text need to be utf-8 encoded and the table field.

Another thing which is often forgotten is to set

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

after opening the connection.

(And, of course, the frontend must be utf-8 encoded.)

Comment: Thanks, what I was missing in php side mysql setting.

Answer (score 1):

To properly use UTF-8 within your web application, make sure that:

1. the connection to the database is UTF-8. This can be set with `mysql_set_charset`, or, when you're not using ext/mysql, via the query `SET NAMES utf8`
2. the varchar/text columns of your database tables uses a UTF-8 character set and collation
3. when working with UTF-8 strings, you use php functions which support multibyte strings. The best solution would be to install the [mbstring](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) extension. If that is not possible, you can use the [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php) functions.
4. your http response headers include a UTF-8 header. This can be set using `header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');`
5. your html page includes a content-type meta tag: `<meta name="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Comment: Thanks, what I was missing in php side mysql setting.